# How to get button title from dynamically generated buttons in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have already dynamically created a row of buttons in my controller implementation class and added them to the view. The title of each button is set to a corresponding number; the first button has a title of "1", the second is "2", and so forth. I would like to do something with the text from the title of the button clicked (for this question I would just like to output it with NSLog).

Is this possible at all? Here is a snippet of code I used to make the buttons:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // position of first button to be created
    int xPos = 31;
    int yPos = 404;

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 30, 30)];
        NSString *buttonTitle = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", i + 1];
        [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view addSubview:button];
        [button addTarget: self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

       xPos = xPos + 38;
    }

}

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    // Do something when each button is clicked
    // something like: NSLog(the button's title)
}
```

I created an account here just to ask this question, hope I formatted my code correctly for this question! Feel free to ask if you have any questions regarding what I need help with.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UIButton` to see how to get the button title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    // Do something when each button is clicked
    NSLog(@"Button title: %@", [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);

}
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, still relatively new to this language and I guess I completely overlooked that I can access the button's properties with sender. I have used "this" in Java to refer to the object that was clicked and I just didn't have a clue how to do that in Objective C